# Preset search term in backgrid.js filter

Tags: javascript, backgrid

In the [documentation](http://wyuenho.github.io/backgrid-filter/api/index.html#!/api/Backgrid.Extension.ClientSideFilter) of the ClientSideFilter I read the following:

> Renders a search form with a text box, optionally with a placeholder
>   and a preset value if supplied during initialization.

I can set a placeholder value during initialization, but how can a preset value be supplied? It is missing from the initialization parameters.

(I would like to be able to link directly to a filtered table so a preset value would come handy.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the preset value mentioned in the documentation refers to the value in the filter's input field.

Initializing your filter with a `value` option, will render the field with that value.

```
var filter = new Backgrid.Extension.ClientSideFilter({
  collection: collection,
  placeholder: "Search",
  value: "PRESET"
});
```

**Edit:** If you want to link to a filtered grid, you'll have to trigger a search for the filter to take effect.
You can do that by calling the filter's `search` function after the filter has been rendered.